# Suppress the Scientific Notation in Numeric Value Output in Html formatted email written in Python

Tags: python, html, sql, pandas, email

Hi I have a dataframe which has 3 columns.I want to send this data in the mail after doing html formatting of text and html.I am getting one of the column values in scientific notation(1.53481e+07) in email.I have used round() function to store the value in dataframe as decimal number.I need the the value to show as decimal number(153481.07) instead of scientific notation in my mail output.Kindly help.I am using the below code

````
import datetime
import psycopg2 as pg
from tabulate import tabulate
import smtplib
import pandas as pd
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Write Query and Connect to Redshift Database
connection = pg.connect(dbname= '<dbname>', host = '<host>', port= '5439', user= '<user_name>', password='<password>')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select 'Exec Dash Revenue' as Metric_Name,SUBSTRING(ptn_dateid_pacific,1,6) as MthYr , sum(grossrev) +sum(shippingrev) + sum(discount) as Metric_value  from dw_bo.f_order_component_mart
where  hierlevel1 not in ('OTHER', 'Progal', 'Discount', 'Shipping', 'Dummy Discount', 'Gift Card', 'Unassigned') and prodsku_base not in ('UNALLOCATED','TP|UNALLOCATED') and experience in ('WEB', 'APP') and orderstatus in ('W_UPLOAD'
                    , 'W_PAYMENT_VER'
                    , 'PAYMENT_VER_REQD'
                    , 'READY'
                    , 'CONVTED_TO_JOBS'
                    , 'INT_PROC'
                    , 'DONE_INT_PROC'
                    , 'SENT'
                    , 'RECEIVED'
                    , 'PROCESSING'
                    , 'DONE_PROCESSING'
                    , 'FULFILLED'
                    , 'FINAL_PROC'
                    , 'DONE_FINAL_PROC'
                    , 'INVOICED'
                    , 'PAYMENT_REQD'
                    , 'PAID'
                    )and ptn_dateid_pacific >= 20200301 and ptn_dateid_pacific <= 20200310 group by 1,2""")
data = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
data[2]=data[2].round(2)
data.index = data.index + 1
cursor.close
connection.close()


text = """
Hello, Friends.

Here is your data:

{table}

Regards,

(name)"""

html = """
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 table, th, td {{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }}
  th, td {{ padding: 5px; }}
</style>
</head>
<body><p>Hello, Friends</p>
<p>Here is your Report:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>(name)</p>
</body></html>
"""
# Set up E-mail
date = datetime.datetime.now()
date = date.strftime('%a %b %d')

fromaddr = '<from_email_address>'
toaddr = ['<to_email_address>']

col_list = ['Metric_Name','MthYr','Metric_value']

text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=col_list, tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=col_list, tablefmt="html"))


#html = str(data_html) % data_html

msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = ', '.join(toaddr)
msg['Subject'] = 'Recon Report - ' + date

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.outlook.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, '<password>')
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())

data[2]="%.2f" % (data[2])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.